# Custom airflow operator does not return values

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I am trying to automate an I created a custom operator in airflow which reads from a custom util plugin what I built and it should return multiple values.

This is a sample of a util I built which reads the data from s3, cleans it and transforms it.

```
ClassA:
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     initialization

 def get_data(self):
     *******
     data import from s3 and 
     data processing script
     ********
  return A,B,C,D,E
```

And this is how my custom operator looks like

```
from util import classA
from airflow.models import BaseOperator
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults
class SFScoreDataOperator(BaseOperator):
    @apply_defaults
  def __init__(self):
      Initialization parameters
  def execute(self, context):
    A,B,C,D,E = ClassA().get_data()
```

What I am trying to do passing those A,B,C,D,E variables to the next operator but airflow throws an error saying

```
A,B,C,D,E = ClassA().get_data()
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

I'd really appreciate if I can get some help with that error

Comment: Could you please provide the actual stack trace?

Comment: Hey @joeb: Can you elaborate what stack trace is?

Comment: Sure thing. The part where you got the "TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable" line from, that whole portion helps to show the path your program's execution took from its start to where it failed.

Comment: ERROR - 'tuple' object is not callable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 930, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/plugins/success_factor_score_operator_v2.py", line 25, in execute
    A,B,C,D,E = SuccessFactorData().get_data()

This is the complete stack trace. Let me know if I can provide anything else

Comment: I hope this helps

Comment: Share the code for `get_data` please. Edit your original question.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5XJ9Ok
Here is the complete code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `get_data` method is decorated with the `@property` decorator which mean it's no longer callable (*it **could** be if you returned a callable but that's besides the point*) -- the decorator makes the `get_data` method behave like an attribute, your `A,B,C,D,E = ClassA().get_data()` is functionally equivalent to this:

```py
A, B, C, D, E = ("Value A", "Value B", "Value C", "Value D", "Value E")
get_data = (A, B, C, D, E)
get_data() # <-- There's your problem, you can't call `tuple` objects.
```

**TLDR**: Remove the `@property` decorator from your `SuccessFactorData.get_data` ore change your usage from `A,B,C,D,E = ClassA().get_data()` to `A,B,C,D,E = ClassA().get_data` -- do one or the other and you should stop receiving your error.

Comment: Ahh rookie mistake!! Thank you so much!

Comment: Posted another question. Really appreciate if you could answer it